# Pass data parameter for ajax call in devbridge autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am using this autocomplete plugin https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

I am using using below lines of code in jQuery

```
$('#text-user').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'index.php?secController=studentProfile&action=employeeSearch',
  onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
  }
});
```

From `php` side it is fetching suggestions from database by below code

```
public
function employeeSearch() {
  $arrayOfEmployee = array();
  $arrayToPush = array();
  $arrayToJSON = array();

  $new_item = $this - > apicaller - > sendRequest(array(
    "controller" => "Employee",
    "action" => "employeeSearch",
    "searchCriteria" => $_REQUEST['searchCriteria']
  ));

  $arrayOfEmployee = json_decode($new_item, true);

  foreach($arrayOfEmployee as $key => $employee) {
    $arrayToPush = array('value' => $employee['FullName'], 'data' => $employee['_id']['$oid']);
    array_push($arrayToJSON, $arrayToPush);
  }

  echo json_encode(["suggestions" => $arrayToJSON]);
}
```

The is coming in proper format for autocomplete. Now the issue is that is fetching all the data all the time. Then I realised it might because of unable to find searchCriteria of textbox which is not passed in ajax like call.

Please help me how to pass searchCriteria for the line `"searchCriteria" =>  $_REQUEST['searchCriteria']` via ajax like call of this plugin?

I tried like

```
$('#text-user').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'index.php?secController=studentProfile&action=employeeSearch',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {
    searchCriteria: this.value
  },
  ....
  ...
```

It still fetch all the employees because in database coding if searchCriteria is left blank, it fetches all the employees

Please help

The data is

```
{"suggestions":[{"data":"Aasiya Rashid Khan","value":"5aa662b0d2ccda095400022f"},{"data":"Sana Jeelani Khan","value":"5aa75d8fd2ccda0fa0006187"},{"data":"Asad Hussain Khan","value":"5aaa51ead2ccda0860002692"}.....
```

Answer (score 1):

you're sending a `POST` request ( using `type: 'POST'` ) so you'll find your variable in a `$_POST` in the server side, but i don't see `POST` in the documentation, so use the default `GET` :

the client side :

```
$('#text-user').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'index.php?secController=studentProfile&action=employeeSearch',
  onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
  }
});
```

server side :

`"searchCriteria" =>  $_REQUEST['query']`

Comment: It is not working because it needs to passed through plugin ajax call.

Comment: it is sent from ajax with a `POST` request

Comment: I was just tweaking the code by using type: 'POST', data: {...} which has not been mentioned this plugin and didn't work. I posted this just for question more understandable...

Comment: sorry it still does not work.... now it does not fetch all the data like it used. it is fetching nothing

Comment: does it work if you hardcode `$_REQUEST['searchCriteria']` ? like `"searchCriteria" => "some criteria"`

Comment: yes it works. but I want that it should fetch dynnamically like if type a, it should fetch all the employees with a in their name

Comment: i just tested it and it's actually `$_REQUEST['query']` that contains your variable and not `$_REQUEST['searchCriteria']` , leave your previously working code and change the variable name in the server side